# Scipy fisher_exact test taking a very long time

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using scipy version 1.0.0.

```
import scipy as sp
x = [[5829225, 5692693], [5760959, 5760959]]
sp.stats.fisher_exact(x)
```

For the values above scipy does not return anything but waits.
What can be the reason for that?
How can I fix it?

However in R it returns a p-value almost immediately.

```
a = matrix(c(5829225,5692693,5760959,5760959), nrow=2)
fisher.test(a)
```

Comment: Try "scipy.stats.fischer_exact(x)" and remove "import scipy as sp"

Comment: No change. It still does not return any p-value.  What should it change with 
    "scipy.stats.fisher_exact(x)" ?

Comment: I think the implementation is just really slow for large N; on my computer it looks like it'll finish, but in about twenty minutes.  You should think about whether or not you really want [Fisher](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa), of course.

Comment: Thanks for [reporting the issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9231); looks like a bug.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser,  You are welcome.

Comment: If you come here because you feel Fisher exact is too slow, see my solution here: stackoverflow.com/questions/34947578/… It computes the answer for millions of rows in a few seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

From the notes in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html):

> The calculated odds ratio is different from the one R uses. This scipy implementation returns the (more common) “unconditional Maximum Likelihood Estimate”, while R uses the “conditional Maximum Likelihood Estimate”.
>
> **For tables with large numbers**, the (inexact) chi-square test implemented in the function [chi2_contingency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html#scipy.stats.chi2_contingency) can also be used.

(Emphasis mine)

Like DSM's comment mentioned, it's probably just very slow for your large values. And since the notes call out large values, you might try the alternative they suggest:

```
>>> chi2, p, dof, expected = sp.stats.chi2_contingency(x)
>>> p
6.140729432506709e-178
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I wonder what is the definition for large number. 3000000? or less? I do some trials :)

Comment: When you have only 2X2 contingency table, fisher exact test is good. chi square test requires at least 5 values I guess.